# Is creating high quality pages on a Wiki and linking back to my site a good link building strategy for Google?

Tags: google, links, backlinks

I recently found two wiki sites that use do-follow links.
I want to post a few high-quality pages there and link back to my site within them.

Is that okay with Google?

Comment: You gain benefit of nofollow links through diversity! unless those links are from relevant on-topic WIKI's and do have other users exploiting the dofollow for self-gain then you should be OK! otherwise you can expect those sites to appear in many disavows on multiple sites, also if admins remove your links that could go against you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is: it depends. Wiki is interchangeable with Wikipedia, and can also mean someone creating their own wiki. 3rd party wikis can obviously be created by good actors and bad actors alike. I can understand that you don't want to give up your link source in fear of others taking advantage of information that probably took you a long time to find.

So, here is what you do:

1. visit Moz's OpenSiteExplorer here: https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/.
2. put in one of your 2 URl's in the search box
3. after the page loads, scroll down on the left and click "Compare Link Metrics"
4. Click "Add Site" and input the remaining websites that you see as potential link partners.

Now, whats the data say? Do they have high domain/page authority? What about trust? Scroll half way down the page to find their respective spam score. Is it a 3 or higher?

Sites with a 3+ spam score with low authority and trust will never make good link partners. Hopefully this helps with your decision. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Creating high quality content for the purpose of embedding your back-links sounds like a time-consuming and risky SEO strategy to me.

Creating a page on a wiki isn't that much different than creating a guest article.   Google started cracking down on "guest blogging" a couple years ago.  Just having content you created pointing to your site is probably enough to get your site penalized if Google catches on.   For example take this case study as a warning: [How A Single Guest Post May Have Gotten An Entire Site Penalized By Google](https://searchengineland.com/guest-post-google-penalty-187707)

After spending many hours creating a high quality wiki page, there is always the risk that it gets removed from the wiki, or your links edited out of it.  That would certainly be the case here if you were to create questions or answers that linked to your site.

I would suggest that it would be a better use of your time to create high quality content for your own site.  Then there is no danger of tripping penalties or having the content removed. High quality content will attract links naturally.